# How do i compare XML file with UI using Selenium with Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I do have almost 450 XML files which contain patient data. I have to compare those data with UI. So initially I thought will convert into Excel and then compare Excel file with UI but when  I converted into Excel it contains lot of unwanted data which manually i have to delete which is very time consuming as file is large some of file having 3500 rows or more or less. Are their another way to convert data and then i can compare with UI.  I google it and found we can convert it into JSON but then how do i compare with UI? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to compare XML data represented on UI form?

Comment: Yes have to compare XML data with application(UI). Like Demographics, Medications etc.

Comment: I do have a XML file for each patient which contain all Demographics, Clinical data and that data has to be compare with application.

Comment: In that case your best bet will be to assert straight away by calling API end point of the UI instead of verifying on UI and assert in API response all the field.

Comment: @Mrunal, Can you elaborate what you suggested as i am not  experienced person.

Comment: When you click or perform any action on UI there's a web-service call made to backend. Core logic and functionality always lies in backend. When you hit that service with input then in response you will get the data that you see on UI. so instead of verifying on UI we take a back door approach and we should hit the web service so that you can compare web service JSON/XML response with your expected XML data.

Comment: @Mrunal, You mean have to use Webservice?

Comment: That's the ideal solution. unless you want to explicitly eat food through your nose .. :)

Comment: My file is C-CDA its a kind of XML which contain all the healthcare detail of patient such as Demographics, Medications, Diagnosis etc.

Comment: doesn't matter until it's a XML file

Comment: @MrunalGosar, Thanks, i am new to Automation testing field, just having knowledge of Selenium and little bit Java, After your Web Service suggestion, i am learning it and come to conclusion with the help of Rest Assured, we can do it. Am i on right path?

Comment: perfect. now shifu master can rest in peace :) as panda has become dragon warrior..hehehehe